# Practical examples of good use of classes?

Tags: class

I am an intermediate-level hobbyist programmer, and in more than a year of recreational coding I have never felt the need to use a class, functions work just fine, I know what classes are (at a basic level) still I have never encountered a single case where I thought "*This would be much simpler and cleaner with a class*". Is this because I do not know classes well enough?

Can you give me an example of a concrete program (not like the 2 lines examples that can be found on many tutorial sites) that with classes is simpler, cleaner and easier to understand?

Comment: There are *tons* of books, articles, and tutorials on object-oriented programming and the patterns employed therein.

Comment: If there are tons of them, then it means that it is hard to find a good one.

Comment: That's an odd conclusion to make.  There is also tons of air in the world, but does that make it difficult to breathe?  One heavily over-used example of object-oriented design would be creating a handful of "car" objects which inherit functionality from abstract parent objects, override functionality for customizations, etc.  Basically any scenario which involves modeling, well, objects.  If all one did was write an ever-growing library of helper functions for an inherently object-based model then the code would become extraordinarily difficult to maintain very quickly.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You don't need a sample program to demonstrate this.

Human is a class.  You are an object of the class Human.  Human contains all of the data which is required and operations which is needs to perform to meet the requirements of a human.  It is comprised of various objects, which are probably classes too, like Arm, Head etc.  It also has various functions like Breath, Sleep, Walk etc.

It derives from a pure virtual class called Mammal.  Mammal is pure virtual and cannot be instantiated as a class by itself.  The reason being you don't get mammals walking around, they have to be a type of mammal.  The Mammal class exists as conceptual convenience.  Anything which overrides Mammal has to explain how it implements any functions which do not work the same for all mammals.

If you wanted to implement the above logic without using classes then you could.  You could write data structures and functions which work on them but there would be many functions which only make sense to certain data structures.  Classes help you group this information together in one logical concept.

Instead of breaking the problem down into programming constructs you can build programming constructs to match the problem.

Comment: Could the dive bomber let me know the issue so I can address it and improve the answer?

Comment: It is explaining the issue with those dumb useless hierarchies that make absolutely no sense and aren't even close to being a good OOP design.

Comment: *scratches head* sorry I did not get a lot of sleep last night!  Do you meant the answer is dumb, the example hierarchy is dumb or that the concept of modelling a hierarchy in this way is dumb ... or all of the above?!!